# Woocommerce hook overflow on Single Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My code in Functions.php displays the text stored in a custom field (using advanced custom field plugin) over the respective WooCommerce product.

My problem is, I can only display this on the Shop/product archive. When I try to hook in the Single Product page thumbnail, it does not work.

How can I hook to main Single Product Page image?

Shop Archive - Displays correctly.
[image]

Single Product Page - Missing on main image, displays on related products only
[image]

My code in functions.php

```
function wpo_before_shop_loop_item_title() {
   if (defined('WPO_IS_ENABLED') && (WPO_IS_ENABLED === false)) {
      // Disabled by configuration.
    }  else {
      $post_id = get_the_ID();

      // Is this a featured product?
      $terms = wp_get_post_terms(
         $post_id,
         'product_visibility',
         array('fields' => 'names')
      );
      $is_featured = in_array('featured', $terms);

      // Get our custom overlay properties.
      $custom_overlay_text = get_post_meta($post_id, 'product_overlay_text', true);
      $is_custom_overlay_visible = boolval(get_post_meta(
         $post_id,
         'is_product_overlay_enabled',
         true
      ));

      // Featured product star.
      if ($is_featured) {
         echo '<div class="prod-overlay prod-overlay-feat">';
         echo '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
         echo '</div>'; // .prod-overlay
      }

      // Custom overlay text.
      if ($is_custom_overlay_visible && !empty($custom_overlay_text)) {
         echo '<div class="prod-overlay prod-overlay-text">';
         printf(
            '<span class="prod-overlay-label">%s</span>',
            esc_html($custom_overlay_text)
         );
         echo '</div>'; // .prod-overlay
      }
   }
}
add_action(
   'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',
   'wpo_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' , 
   9
);
```

Comment: Please also add CSS as well that you added for overlay text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_product_thumbnails` action hook. try the below code.

```
function woocommerce_product_thumbnails_single_product() {

    if( is_product() ){

        global $product;

        if (defined('WPO_IS_ENABLED') && (WPO_IS_ENABLED === false)) {
          // Disabled by configuration.
        }  else {
            $post_id = $product->get_id();

            // Is this a featured product?
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms(
                $post_id,
                'product_visibility',
                array('fields' => 'names')
            );
            $is_featured = in_array('featured', $terms);

            // Get our custom overlay properties.
            $custom_overlay_text = get_post_meta($post_id, 'product_overlay_text', true);
            $is_custom_overlay_visible = boolval(get_post_meta(
                $post_id,
                'is_product_overlay_enabled',
                true
            ));

            // Featured product star.
            if ($is_featured) {
                echo '<div class="prod-overlay prod-overlay-feat">';
                echo '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                echo '</div>'; // .prod-overlay
            }

            // Custom overlay text.
            if ($is_custom_overlay_visible && !empty($custom_overlay_text)) {
                echo '<div class="prod-overlay prod-overlay-text">';
                printf(
                    '<span class="prod-overlay-label">%s</span>',
                    esc_html($custom_overlay_text)
                );
                echo '</div>'; // .prod-overlay
            }
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails','woocommerce_product_thumbnails_single_product' );
```

**Tested and Works**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` hook is only executed for products being rendered in a loop ([source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php#L42)). You need to use one of the hooks that are actually executed on the single product page. For identifying the correct hook, you can for example use the [Visual Hook Guide](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) or the [WooCommerce Source Code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php).